# Making item selected in RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml

I have a RadioButtonList which is populated with 2 fields, Male and Female. They are populated using TableAdapters, this is my code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="gender_radioBtn" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" style="display:inline" Width="288px" DataSourceID="genderObject" DataTextField="gender" DataValueField="id">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="genderObject" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="getGenders" TypeName="registerTableAdapters.genderTableAdapter"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I want the Male which has a Value of 1 to be selected without having to do it programatically on PageLoad.

Does any know what should be done to achieve Male being selected within the RadioButtonList when the page is loaded without programitcally doing so in the PageLoad event?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's wrong with doing it at page load?

Comment: @user2366842 I was just wondering wouldn't it be overrided? For example if I set the SelectedValue to be 1 in PageLoad and a user clicks the register button which the user set the SelectedValue as 2 it will automatically be overridden by the PageLoad as it sets it to 1?

Comment: There's a property called `IsPostback`, and it can be checked for at page load...my C# is a little rusty (I'm more into the world of VB these days) but it should be something along the lines of `If !IsPostBack ` or so.  Only populate the initial selection of Male at that point.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx related MSDN article...put your code to check Male where they're using the validate function.

Comment: @user2366842 Thank you, can I ask what would the main purpose of isPostBack be? Does it check if a page has been refreshed?

Comment: It checks if the page itself is performing a postback (reload) or if it's the first time the page has been loaded.  If you're pushing a button, or doing some other functionality with autopostback=true, this will trigger a postback to the page, and cause the page_load event to be hit.  If you have code within that sort of block, it will be skipped over and not executed.

Comment: @user2366842 Thanks dude, should put it as a answer so I can mark it down. Thanks again!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can actually be done within the page load function, as was discussed in the comments.  You will want to check the `IsPostBack` property of the page to determine if the page is being loaded for the first time, or if it's performing a postback.

Example code slightly modified from MSDN:

```
  private void Page_Load()
  {
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
          //Put your code to check the Male Radio Button here.
     }
  }
```

Related MSDN link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx